# MSAcces find T1.C1_long_text not in T2.C1_long_text

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello im new to acces and I am tring to do something like where the field C1 is Long Text

```
Select T1.C1
FROM T1,T2
WHERE T1.C1 !=(NOT IN) T2.C1
```

If i do the

```
Select T1.C1
FROM T1,T2
WHERE T1.C1 = T2.C1
```

I got the expected results I see the fields that are equal in the same table.
but when I try to use the <> it crashes.

Help pls.

Comment: The question *is* about SQL, even if it is the Access-specific dialect / implementation of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery.  For your original logic, this looks like:

```
SELECT T1.C1
FROM T1
WHERE T1.C1 NOT IN (SELECT T2.C1 FROM T2);
```

I actually recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T1.C1
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.C1 = T1.C1);
```

This handles `NULL` values in `T2` more intuitively.

**Note from asker:** Acces does not allow joins on MEMO (long text) data.

Comment: Note: Access does not allow joins on MEMO (long text) data.